# Why do I need to qualify a named content type from the "type" attribute of a local XSD element?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have an XSD file like this:

```
<schema xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://myns.com"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <complexType name="playerInfo">
    <sequence>
      <element name="level" type="integer" />
    </sequence>
  </complexType>

  <element name="player">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name="name" type="string" />
        <element name="info" type="playerInfo" />
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>

</schema>
```

Now my IDE throws an error, saying it "cannot resolve symbol 'playerInfo'" in the `type` attribute of the local `info` element declaration.
But if I add a namespace alias `xmlns:target="http://myns.com"` to the `<schema>` tag, and then change that `type` attribute to `type="target:playerInfo"`, the error goes away. I've seen it done in other tutorials, so I know it's right. But I'm confused: why qualify the `type` attribute value with the target namespace? How did the global complexType automatically have a connection with the target namespace? For what I know, the default namespace for the schema is w3.org's path, so how does the complexType have anything to do with the target namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to understand here.

First, all global schema components have a name which is a QName comprising the `targetNamespace` of the containing schema document, together with the local name given in the `name` attribute.

Secondly all attributes that reference global schema components, such as `ref` and `type`, are instances of `xs:QName`, and as such, if they are unprefixed then they represent names in no namespace.

So your type has name (in XPath 3.0 notation) `Q{http://myns.com}playerInfo`, but the type attribute expands to `Q{}playerInfo`.

Comment: It's amazing these intricacies are none that would be explained in most tutorials. Could you suggest a site where I could find more of such deep information?

Comment: One clarifying point, the default namespace is defined as ``xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"``, which means unprefixed ``xs:QName``'s have that namespace, rather than no namespace. So the ``type`` attribute actually expands to ``Q{https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}playerInfo`` (which also does not match ``Q{http://myns.com}playerInfo``). Note that this is why you can use ``type="string"``--that expands to ``Q{https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string``, which is a valid type defined in XSD.

Comment: @EmmanueL Books are usually a much better source than online tutorials. You know that they are written by experts, who have spent a significant time designing the structure, and that the material has been carefully checked before publication. People producing free tutorials don't devote six months of their life to the project in the same way. There are good books on XML Schema by Eric van Der Vlist and by Priscilla Walmsley. Both are good; I would say Priscilla is better at explaining things, while Eric is more comprehensive.